# How to change mm/dd/yyyy to desired format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I have date in format mm/dd/yy.For eg:4/1/2009 means April 1 2009.I want to get format as April 1,2009 in sql.Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you want this directly from your SQL query, or can you use other code to translate it on the front end?

Comment: Something (your profile, maybe) tells me that you're obsessed with dates! Maybe you should get yourself a date, now! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the CONVERT function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

It looks like format 107 is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
DECLARE @date datetime
SET @date = getdate()
SELECT datename(day,@date) + ' ' + left(datename(month,@date),3) + ' ' + datename(year,@date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @d datetime
select @d = '20090401'

select convert(varchar(50),@d,107)
```

will give you  this

Apr 01, 2009

If you want 1 instead of 01 do this

```
declare @d datetime
select @d = '20090401'

select replace(convert(varchar(50),@d,107),' 0',' ')
```

Apr 1, 2009